# How to enable RDP on a machine connected to a domain

Tags: windows

I have a machine connected to a domain, I have a shell with system level privileges, how can I enable RDP? even though I enabled it, it doesn't listen on port  3389. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: What version of Windows? Windows Home or Pro? RDP is built into Windows Pro from around XP and up. C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe

Comment: Are you looking for Command Line instructions, or are you willing to entertain other ideas? I'm going to assume this a Windows Server Core?

Comment: Kindly check if methods in this article was helpful: [How to Enable Remote Desktop On Windows](https://softwarekeep.com/help-center/how-to-enable-remote-desktop-on-windows#:~:text=The%20easiest%20way%20to%20enable,in%20the%20Remote%20Desktop%20section.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to this the CLI way, there are two methods. Here are the commands to try:

1. reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
2. netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="remote desktop" new enable=Yes

The first will enable it in the registry, you might have to reboot to take affect. The second sets up the firewall rule.

As an alternative: In my domain, I created a GPO to enable the RDP on the machines.